# Retrieving user input and posting within HTML

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I am looking at "HTML" and "JavaScript" and I have a **prompt box** that asks for the "users name", I was wondering if there's a way of then posting the name they have entered onto the webpage.

To give a bit of background I am creating a game and once the user has entered their name I would like to display it underneath a canvas that contains the game, alongside their score, here is what I have so far.

Code:

```
var player=prompt("Please enter your name");

if (player!=null)
{
x="Hello " + player + ;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: Should not have a plus sign after player?

Comment: The problem is that once it has taken the users name, I want to display the name on the page. At the moment the user enters their name  however it does not appear anywhere on the page

Comment: are you sure you have an html element with id "demo"?

Comment: What does your JavaScript error console say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your opening `body` tag to this:

```
<body onload="placeName();">
```

Then, your JS file should look like this:

```
function placeName(){
  var name = prompt("Enter name");
  if (name != null){
    var greeting = "Hello " + player + "!";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
  }
}
```

You also need to make sure that you have a `div` or something of the sort with the id `demo` to actually change when the `function` runs. That's extremely important. The only thing that's different above from what you did is that it waits until the body loads to prompt the user. Your JS file may have loaded before your `document`, which could cause issues. Also make sure that you have linked your JS file to your HTML file or have put it in `script` tags in the head. If none of that works, check your console for errors and put it in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that we can see all of your code to check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x;
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");

    if (person !== null) {
        x = "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_prompt